# Image depending on the text in Python/Django

Tags: django, image, keyword

How can I find an image, depending on the text?

I have image model with keywords:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(_('Image'), blank=True, upload_to='folder')
    keywords = models.CharField(_('Keywords'), max_length=80)
```

And model which will serve as the search for a suitable image

```
class TextSearch(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(_('Text'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
# Set to search for posts with keyword 'cute'
search = TextSearch(body="cute") 

# Go run the search
results = Post.objects.filter(keywords__contains=search.body)
```

This will give you every `Post` with the `TextSearch`'s `body` in the `keywords`. If that's not what you want, you might want to check [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/) for a full list of Django's *QuerySet methods*.

Comment: What to do if body is a big text?